# Ignore / Omit Items in a Collection based on Property

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, listbox, silverlight-5.0

So what I'm doing is I have a collection that interacts with a couple different elements. One has dependency on all the items and another doesn't need all of them. As an example, Element A, needs all items but carries a `{x:Null}` `DisplayName` on some of them, so I tried to use that in Element B to omit it from listing as an item in a `ListBox` like;

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
     <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding DisplayName, Converter={StaticResource nullVisConv}}">

        .....

     </StackPanel>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

This of course just sets the visibility on the parent of the `DataTemplate` so if it's Null, than Visibility="Collapsed" right?

Problem is, it still generates as an Item but doesn't show the contents so you end up with a blank Item on a listbox that will still respond to things like MouseOver and takes up space. Obviously not the best route so I'm hoping for an education here.

How can we omit and ignore an Item entirely from being displayed based on the property `DisplayName` if it equals {x:Null}? This would be handy to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with bindings on the `DataTemplate`. I think you need to filter/modify your collection before it is bound to the `ListBox`'s `ItemSource` property.

Comment: See that's where I'm running into an issue, because both elements need to share the same ItemSource since they interact with one another. Unless you're saying I can go filter the results of the collection and supply two separate ItemSources but still allow them to interact? If that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking in your ViewModel you'd have the one property that is your actual collection, and then a second property that returns a filtered version of the first property. So the items would be shared. Without knowing what you mean by "interact with one another" I can't tell for sure, but it seems like that would work...

Comment: Ya was afraid of that, but was trying to keep it simple in explanation. So if I have a map with layers as the collection items, the listbox allows the users to interact with those layers in various ways. Except a few of the Items(layers) don't need to be interacted with or even shown outside of the map itself as a layer. I just want to to take the items not needed for display in the ListBox out entirely but I have to keep them in the same collection or they can't interact back and forth and filtering would create a separate collection from what I've seen. It's confusing... haha

Comment: I think i'm more or less following, but still not sure about the "interact" part. You're right that filtering would create a separate collection. But from your description that seems ok as long as its the same objects in the two collections. Any changes made to the objects in the filtered list (used in the listbox) would also be made to the objects in the non-filtered list (used on the map) automatically.

Comment: hmm ya I'm going to have stew on this one a little, tough trying to ask specific questions while trying to respect the whole proprietary confidentiality crap....but it's Friday so meh...on that note I think your thoughts are correct in concept anyway so counting as answered.